# log4j cannot find the log4jtest.properties?

Tags: java, log4j

When I use 
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4jtest.properties");

I put this file in the root folder of classes.

The eclipse reports

> log4j:ERROR Could not read
>   configuration file [log4j.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   log4j.properties (The system cannot
>   find the file specified)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your properties file is in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it's being copied to the output folder with the compile classes. That ones got me before :-)